# python svgwrite can't add class attribute?

Tags: python, svg, svgwrite

I'm trying to correct the following code:

```
import svgwrite
dwg = svgwrite.Drawing('test.svg', profile='tiny')
dwg.add(dwg.circle((10, 0), 20 , fill='rgb(0,0,255)', id='rrr', class='#t'))
dwg.save()
```

I get the following error:

```
dwg.add(dwg.circle((10, 0), 20 , fill='rgb(0,0,255)', id='rrr', class='#t'))
                                                                    ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax
```

Why is that? Apparently svgwrite can't add a class attribute to elements

Comment: `class` is a keyword in Python, try `**{'class': '#t'}))`

Answer (score 7):

According to the [svgwrite documentation](http://pythonhosted.org/svgwrite/classes/base.html) you must add a trailing underscore to attributes which are python keywords. So the correct code would be:

```
dwg.add(dwg.circle((10, 0), 20 , fill='rgb(0,0,255)', id='rrr', class_='#t'))
```